# Remove padding/border/frame from ListView items

Tags: android

I'm having these grey separation bars between my list items which I can't seem to remove. I'm done with tag-guessing.

The layout file for the layout containing my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/what">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Post the layout files, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `android:dividerHeight="0px"` and `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"` on your ListView.

Like:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: Fill_parent was deprecated in 2011, use match_parent instead.

Comment: Got it thanks! By any chance.. did you ever unattach the logcat Window from your IDE? If you're - by any chance - using Android Studio .. (have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept your answer)

Comment: Which version of AS are you running? Generally clicking the gear and changing Pin tab or Floating tab did it for me.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. There is no gear button. I somehow have just a stupid single window of logcat and no Idea how I can re-attach it..

Comment: I answered to your question.